# Pathfinding with prerequisite(must-pass) nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

The problem is to have `one source` finding the shortest path to pass/reach `multiple destinations` with some prerequisite node.

An example would be, I have the algorithm starts from `node A`.there are `B,C,.....Z` out there as available nodes. And every dot is connected to every other node. Say I want to get to node `X,Y and Z`, before I initiate the path finding, I want to make sure that it passes `node F` before reaching `X,Y or Z`

Can this be done using Dijkstra with some minor modification?

Edit:

I had a rough drawing showing how routes might be. 
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/488218415830878575/

Comment: Find the shortest path from `A` to `F`. Then find the shortest paths from `F` to `X, Y, Z`. Of course this introduces the possibility that nodes may be visited twice, such as `A..Q..F..Q..X`.

Comment: To avoid the visiting twice bit, if it's important, then once you have your path from `A` to `F` (but not `F` itself), remove all nodes in that path (and their incident edges) from your graph before finding the path from `F` to something else... That, of course, leaves the possibility that no further path may be possible, which might not be the case using an alternate path from `A` to `F`, but your problem description isn't quite detailed enough to determine what should be done in such cases...

Comment: @twalberg Then you fall into the trap of possibly having to check every combination of nodes for a path from `A..F` that doesn't use up the nodes necessary to get from `F` to the goal nodes. In my example, `Q` might be necessary to get from `F..X` but there might be another route from `A..F` that doesn't include `Q`.

Comment: @beaker Yes... I'm not sure there's a satisfactory algorithm if re-visiting nodes is not allowed - it gets complicated... I was trying to hint at that, but perhaps was not quite clear enough...